# Is it Possible to Run a Webpack/Create-React-App Dev Server *Within* an Express App

Tags: express, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, devserver

I understand that the normal use case for a React/Express app is to run one dev server for your Express app, and one for your React app.  My question is, is it at all possible to run the front-end dev server *within* an Express app, such that:

- I can start both with `node index.js`
- (optional) the two servers share a common port

In other words, is there any way to programmatically start a Webpack dev server from within Node/Javascript (*with JS*; *not* using something like `execute` to run `npm start`), and if so is there anything special about the create-react-app dev server that would prevent running it programmatically?

**EDIT:** I found https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware, which is almost what I'm looking for.  However, it's Webpack, not create-react-app, so while it does allow for hot reloading, it doesn't preserve state between reloads (the way create-react-app's version of Webpack's server does).

So it seems I'm really looking for a `create-react-app-dev-server-middleware` ... or a way to configure the `webpack-dev-middleware` to support `create-react-app`'s state preservation between hot reloads.

Comment: the webpack dev server is running express, you could eject your app and make whatever changes in the existing express server. though this seems like a really unusual use case. what are you actually to acheive?

Comment: and sure you can always import the express app into your other node application and call `.listen()` or whatever the result of calling `npm start` does

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a dev server that starts as a single server and (ideally) runs on a single port.  There is no "live version" of this particular Express server, so I just need one server that can run arbitrary Node commands (ie. an Express server) and can hot reload React front-end files.

Comment: And yes I understand I can change which port my Express app listens on, but I still wind up with two servers, that have to be started/restarted separately, each running on two ports.  Since there is clearly a way to run the Webpack dev server (ie. the thing create-react-app uses to run its dev server) as Express middleware, it *seems* I should be able to do something similar to get the create-react-app functionality (as middleware).